# Angular JS not a function , got undefined in ng-view

Tags: angularjs

When including angular scripts (e.g. Controller.js) not normal scripts in angular view it does not work (not a function, got undefined error) , while if i add them in the main view , it works , does any one know what's the problem

Comment: it is a good practice to include scripts in the main file.

Comment: but including all scripts in the same main view for all diff. templates is against performance optimization , right?

Comment: no its not. I always include scripts in the index.html file and include my code in controller.js

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to include all scripts in the main `index.html` file, not in a template loaded by `ng-view` or `ui-view`. The views get loaded dynamically, so it'll give you problems.

Comment: but isn't it a bad thing as performance issue to load all the scripts for all the different templates in the main view?

Comment: You load them after everything else is loaded, so the user won't really notice much of a difference. Some essential scripts will be in the head, and the performance hogs in the body.